# When should genetic algorithm's variation operators be specialized?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

Genetic algorithm (GA) is *general purpose* metaheuristic often used in computational science, e.g. computational physics. However, some authors of computational physics software, e.g. [1], tend to *specialize* GA to the given problem on the level of variation operators. I do appreciate this approach and their work, but I wonder if it is really necessary to specialize GA's variation operators instead of relying on canonical ones easily available in GA litearature. In other words, I wonder if it is perfectly fine to limit GA specialization to genetic representation (genotype) and genotype/phenotype mapping only.

My questions:

1. Should variation operators be ever specialized to the problem?
2. [Optionally] Is there any criterion to know *a priori* if variation operator specialization is necessary?

Could you please *optionally* support your answer with literature reference(s)?

[1] David C. Lonie and Eva Zurek. "XtalOpt: An open-source evolutionary algorithm for crystal structure prediction". *Computer Physics Communications* **182**.2 (2011) pp. 372-387 DOI: [10.1016/j.cpc.2010.07.048](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2010.07.048)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually better to customize your approach to things that you know about your specific problem. NFL (the No Free Lunch theorems) applies here, so on average across all possible problem instances, everything performs equally. This implies that there are some problems where approach A will outperform approach B, and then on the complement of that set of problems, B will outperform A. And we don't know a lot about how to construct those sets. So there's not a lot of formal theory to guide you here.

In practice though, solving a specific problem is usually easier than solving a general one. Small search spaces are usually easier to work with than larger ones. There are multiple ways to think about that general idea, but the gist is something like this. Let's say I have a problem I've encoded solutions for as a 128 bit string that I decode into whatever parameters. If I know from domain knowledge that the best solutions are likely to start with 16 consecutive ones, I can build my operators to generate such strings more often than uniform random chance would do, and my algorithm will probably work better. If I have a knapsack problem where I know that taking too many items will put me over capacity making for an infeasible solution, my algorithm will virtually always perform better if I make my search operators favor sparser candidates that are under or near the capacity limit.

You have a fixed budget of computational resources to apply to evaluating possible solutions. Customizing your search operators is a way to force the algorithm to spend more of that budget looking at solutions that are plausibly useful.

It's not impossible that an off-the-shelf search algorithm outperforms a customized one. We're not perfect and can make mistakes that lead to the customized algorithm doing specifically *bad* things. And sometimes the world just works out that way. Maybe you have a problem where you really need to spend more time out in the weeds because there's some information out there that's vital to exploit. But it's not what I'd expect most of the time. The advantage of an off-the-shelf search method is that it's quick and easy to deploy, and it may be good enough. I'd usually expect to be able to beat it with careful thought put towards operator design though.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *necessary*.  But customizing the operators might yield better results (either faster convergence, or higher-quality solutions).  In some cases this kind of customization can help a lot.  In others it might not help much, or at all.

There's no surefire way to know a priori whether customization will help.  The only way to know is to try it and see.  Or, you can search the academic literature: if you can find someone who has tried solving a similar problem and published their work, then you can learn from their experience.